# Webpack css-loader UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The module created for a LoaderDependency must have an original source

Tags: webpack, css-loader, postcss-loader, less-loader

All the plugins listed below are on the latest version.
less-loader: 7.2.1
css-loader: 5.0.1
file-loader: 6.2.0
postcss-loader: 4.1.0
extract-loader: 5.1.0
autoprefixer: 10.2.1

My postcss config:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require('autoprefixer')],
};
```

I have the following rule in my webpack (5) config:

```
        test: /\.less$/,
        /* include: [
          settings.PATHS.CSS_SOURCE,
          ...settings.PATHS.CSS_FEATURES_SOURCE,
        ], */
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: cssOptions,
          },
          {
            loader: 'extract-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 2,
              sourceMap: process.env.npm_lifecycle_event.indexOf('watch') > -1,
              url: false,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                config: path.resolve(__dirname, '../postcss.config.js'),
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                paths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

I'm using the importLoaders: 2 because I saw in the documentation for css-loader this would be necesarry if the previous loaders did something to the @import's too?
Now I'm getting the following error:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The module created for a LoaderDependency must have an original source
    at compilation.handleModuleCreation.err (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\LoaderPlugin.js:79:16)
    at buildModule.err (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1556:8)
    at hooks.result.callAsync.hookError (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\AsyncQueue.js:281:5)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncQueue._handleResult (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\AsyncQueue.js:254:21)
    at _processor (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\AsyncQueue.js:237:11)
    at _modulesCache.store.err (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1263:15)
    at C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:69:3
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at Cache.store (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:107:20)
```

When I delete the importLoaders property, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sources' of undefined
    at cssWithMappingToString (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\css-loader\dist\runtime\cssWithMappingToString.js:25:33)
    at C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\css-loader\dist\runtime\api.js:14:21
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toString (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\css-loader\dist\runtime\api.js:13:17)
    at extractExports (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\extract-loader\lib\extractLoader.js:182:269)
    at C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\extract-loader\lib\extractLoader.js:171:45
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at C:\Projects\Carglass\carglass930-source\src\Projects\Platform\code\node_modules\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
```

What am I doing wrong?
This started happening after I upgraded css-loader to v5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly the problem was with extract-loader not being compatible with css-loader v5.
I downgraded css-loader to v4, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in css-loader@5.2.7 - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/releases/tag/v5.2.7.